# Ensure all Jar files that are run, are signed, and are signed by me?

Tags: java, kotlin, jarsigner, jar-signing

I have a Java Desktop application. I'm trying to find a way to download updated jars, and run them without my users having to completely re-install their application. I need to do this safely, and want to verify that 1. the Jars I run haven't been modified, and 2. the Jars I run were signed by me.

Because of how MSIX works, and the new standards for mac os applications, I either can't, or am not supposed to modify my application directories, meaning that I have to save my new jars in an unsafe location, like the User Data directory, or the home directory, where any application can modify them.

**How can I ensure that the JVM only runs signed jars, validates them, and only allow signed jars by me?**

Comment: IMHO if the user's computer is compromised to the point you can't trust the application files downloaded and stored on the disk, verifying the signatures won't help much. The attacker could simply modify your code and disable the verification. The signature could only protect against a tempered file during the download, and for this using HTTPS should be enough.